# Localization For Two Different Regions/Domains with the Same Language

Tags: wordpress, localization, dns

I have a Wordpress site which is based in US (ex. www.example.com). We've been tasked to create a UK/GB version of the site which has it's own domain (ex. www.example.co.uk), but shares the same common pages/posts/backend. About 75% of the pages are the same on both versions but there will be a few sections (like About and Contact) where they are different to account for regional differences.

**Example**

US site (www.example.com) has 4 Pages:

- **Home**
- **About**
- **Services**
- **Contact**

UK Site (www.example.co.uk) also has 3 pages (2 different, 1 the same)

- **Home** (The same as US, but the URL should be www.example.co.uk)
- **About** (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/about)
- **Services** (The same as US, but URL should be www.example.co.uk/services)
- **Contact** (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/contact)

How do I go about setting up the UK/GB version of the site which use the same backend and most of the same content from the base site, but has a few page differences and different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [WPML](http://wpml.org/) plugin, it allows tranlations of posts, pages, categories, menus, and plugins that have language files. It will let your end use login from the same admin area, and then add translations to the existing content.

The tricky bit will be setting it up to work on domain detection, normally it works on a subdomain, or add's a variable to the end of the URL, like ?lang=uk

But that said it should be possible though with a bit of tinkering to setup something based on the URL. And the documentation is pretty comprehensive. Good luck!

Comment: Domain direction is really really tricky, I've still battling on it and there's no good way to do it using this WPML.

Comment: Maybe in combination with http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to make it differently. For our shops we pretend there's a new domain, but in fact there isn't. This also works for SEO because we do make sure the language tags and such are correct. We replace only a few parts such as a few javascripts and conversion pixels and then we are done. See for example on Keepershandschoenen-shop.be. This site is in fact a clone so we don't need wpml. We don't even need a wordpress, magento or whatever CMS installation...

So then you have the same backend, with .com acting as .co.uk also.